# What is better to keep in memory--a string or an object?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm coding an kinda complex application in Excel VBA.

Although I usually avoid global variables, keeping almost every variable in local procedure scope, there are a couple values I need to maintain in global variables.

One of them is a reference to a worksheet in the same workbook. There are many (possibly more then a dozen) different sheets, among which I need to remember one who will be used in the main sub and two different functions.

So I have two options: or I store a reference to the target sheet between functions, or I would need to run again 40 lines of code processing to discover what is the correct function. I think this is not the hardest of the choices.

My two problems are in the best way to store the reference, in terms of system memory performance.

1. The sheet reference is set in a function (which discover the correct sheet and retrieves the information); will be used in the main sub; and is used also in another function (which, in the end, will register the new information in the sheet, if confirmed by user).
   Is it better **(a)** to use a global variable, which can be refered in the main sub and in the two functions; or **(b)** a local variable in the main sub, pass it `ByRef` (still empty/nothing) to the first function, in which I'll assign it the correct value, and further pass it to the second function?
2. Is it better **(a)** to store this reference as a global `string` with the name of the worksheet, and use the global string inside each function to set a local variable with the reference to the sheet (`Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets (stringWithName)`), or **(b)** to store the reference as a global `Excel.Worksheet` object and use it directly inside each procedure? (and set it to `Nothing` after I finish using it of course, after all I'm not a psycho)?

Comment: Are these sheets in `ThisWorkbook`? If so, refer to the worksheet by [codename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename). Good reading [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/code-name-sheet1/) too.

Comment: Yes, they're in the same workbook. Thank you for the links!

Comment: Wow! The article was enlightening, but it doesn't address the performance issue. I'm trying to understand what's quicker for the machine to process.

Comment: If they're in the same workbook, then just use the codename and don't worry about performance

Comment: Hail, Big Ben! Don't you want to write this as an answer, for me to pick it as an answer?

Comment: No, because it is a bit of an opinion-based question.